# The row overlap between multi-level and primary groups of POI is not effective

Tags: apache-poi

1. maven version

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. code demo

```
    private static void collapseRow() throws IOException {
        try (SXSSFWorkbook wb2 = new SXSSFWorkbook(100)) {
            SXSSFSheet sheet2 = wb2.createSheet("new sheet");

            int rowCount = 20;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                sheet2.createRow(i);
            }
            //The first stage
            sheet2.groupRow(0, 10);
            //second stage
            sheet2.groupRow(1, 2);
            //second stage
            sheet2.groupRow(5, 6);
            //second stage
            sheet2.groupRow(8, 10);
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("outlining_collapsed.xlsx")) {
                wb2.write(fileOut);
            } finally {
                wb2.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

3. sheet2.groupRow(8, 10); Why didn't it take effect
   [sheet2.groupRow(8, 10); Why didn't it take effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyWuR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not even possible using `Excel` itself.

The first stage `sheet2.groupRow(0, 10);` creates outline level 1 from row 1 (row index 0) to row 11 (row index 10) having the outline level handler in row header of row 12.

The second stage `sheet2.groupRow(1, 2);` and `sheet2.groupRow(5, 6);` creates two groups in outline level 2 having outline level handlers in row headers of rows 4 and 8.

Then `sheet2.groupRow(8, 10);` tries creating another group in outline level 2 from row 9 (row index 8) to row 11 (row index 10). But then the outline level handler would must be in row header of row 12. But this is not possible because there is outline level handler of outline level 1 already. One row cannot have two different outline level handlers.

Grouping `sheet2.groupRow(8, 9);` would work.

Or you would must have row 12 in outline level 1 using `sheet2.groupRow(0, 11);` , so outline level handler for that outline level would be in row 13.

If you would try grouping rows 9 to 11 in `Excel` after your code has created the `outlining_collapsed.xlsx`, this would create a new outline level for those rows. This would look like so:

[image]

I doubt that this is what you want. And `apache poi` will not create this using it's high level classes. It could be achieved using the underlying low level classes but not using `SXSSF` because this does not have access to the underlying low level classes.

Example using `XSSF`:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

class CreateExcelGroupRowsTest {

 private static void collapseRow() throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook wb2 = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
   XSSFSheet sheet2 = wb2.createSheet("new sheet");

   int rowCount = 20;
   for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    sheet2.createRow(i);
   }
   //The first stage
   sheet2.groupRow(0, 10);
   //second stage
   sheet2.groupRow(1, 2);
   //second stage
   sheet2.groupRow(5, 6);

   //second stage
   sheet2.groupRow(8, 10);
   //set new outline level for rows 9 to 11
   for (int r = 8; r <= 10; r++) {
    sheet2.getRow(r).getCTRow().setOutlineLevel((short)3);
   }

   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("outlining_collapsed.xlsx")) {
    wb2.write(fileOut);
   } finally {
    //wb2.dispose();
   }
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  collapseRow();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. I try to operate in Excel. As you said, it's impossible. But I think it's unreasonable